# Windows Embedded Compact webservices.dll

Tags: web-services, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded

On http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/windows-ce/tegra/release-details?view=release-roadmap&issue=10304 it is stated that one should "Copy webservices.dll manually to the target folder \Flashdisk\System\" in order to fix a problem with Ethernet debugging. My problem is that I have no idea where I should copy the file from. Any ideas?

This is for WEC2013.

Answer (score 0):

The file is located in your platform builder path if you build your own CE image:

*C:\WINCE800\public\COMMON\oak\target\ARMV7\retail\webservices.dll*

If you use a Toradex Prebuilt image, get in contact with the support team, they will probably send the driver to you: https://www.toradex.com/support/support.